# How to read value form generic method with List<T> as parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Maybe a silly question, I can read all the properties from list parameter but not the value in the fields of `<T>`.

This is the structure

```
    public class TestRecord {
          public string StringTest { get; set; }
          public int IntegerTest { get; set; }
          public DateTime DateTimeTest { get; set; }
    }
```

The generic method

```
    public void TestOfT<T>(List<T> pList) where T:class, new() {
        T xt = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        foreach (var tp in pList[0].GetType().GetProperties()) {
        // System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = xt.GetType().GetProperty("StringTest");
        // object s = pi.GetValue(tp, null) ;  -- failed
            Debug.WriteLine(tp.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(tp.PropertyType);
            Debug.WriteLine(tp.GetType().Name);
        }
     }
```

Test code for generic method

```
    public void TestTCode()  {
        List<TestRecord> rec = new List<TestRecord>();
        rec.Add(new TestRecord() {
             StringTest = "string",
             IntegerTest = 1,
             DateTimeTest = DateTime.Now
        });
        TestOfT<TestRecord>(rec);
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: you say `--failed` but what **exactly** failed?  is it a compile error?  runtime?  what?

Comment: you don't need that `xt` instance at all, since you're just calling `GetType()` on it.  In fact, you don't need to call `GetType()` on any instance.  You can just say `typeof(T).GetProperties()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is you are reading the value from the new instance (which can be written simply as `var xt = new T();`.

if you want to get the property of the item you need to pull the value from the instance.

```
void TestOfT<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T: class, new()
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var item in list)
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var name = property.Name;
        var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", name, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void TestOfT<T>(List<T> pList) where T:class, new() {
    var xt = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach (var tp in pList[0].GetType().GetProperties()) {
        Debug.WriteLine(tp.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(tp.PropertyType);
        Debug.WriteLine(tp.GetType().Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(tp.GetValue(pList[0], null));
    }
 }
```

Comment: This looks like a copy of the code in the question. What's the point?

Comment: I've added the GetValue() method :)

Comment: Now I known my mistake was passing in the tp into GetValue which should be the record.

      Debug.WriteLine(tp.GetValue(pList[0], null));

instead of

      Debug.WriteLine(tp.GetValue(tp, null));

Comment: Yeah, you should provide the object which you want to get the value from.